# Custom SQL Exception Error message in Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, resultset, sqlexception

I have a JFrame which contains a form with 3 fields, one which is the name field and one which is the house no and postcode field, this is used to find a customer details.

This works fine when the correct information is entered, and displays what I want it to inside a JTable. However if one of the fields in entered incorrectly and the information is not found, is it possible to have a custom error message to display?

At the moment the error that appears is: 'ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.' is it possible to customise the message for this scenario when the information is not found without having to lose the SQL exception altogether for other scenarios where errors occur?

Comment: can you show your related code?

Comment: You can always use the exception-chaining mechanism to throw a new exception (perhaps an application-specific one) and attach the `SQLException` to it as a cause.

Comment: @Bhushan i dont think that is necessary, all i want is an exception that I can add to the catch (SQLException err) to display an error when the information is not found, the code itself works perfectly however, so no need to display it

Comment: This message indicates a programming bug, that must be fixed. You should not get such an exception. And the exception message is pretty clear. If you want more help, post your code, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Assign the result of your call to `next()` on your `ResultSet` to a boolean variable, then check its value before you proceed.  Deliver whatever message you like in the event that it is `false`.

Comment: @JBNizet the reason it appears is because it is a search field, when the correct information is entered it works as it uses rs.first(); so it brings up the first value, when incorrect information is entered and it cannot find it, that is the reason it brings that error up

Comment: @John I guess we can point you to the code which gives you `ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next` exception. If you handle `ResultSet` properly then it will not give you the exception you are getting now.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think I will try that, however I am using first() so it brings the first result up when correct information is entered

Comment: That's the problem: you should check if rs.first() returns true, instead of ignoring its result. If you posted your code, we could help, instead of guessing.

Comment: @JBNizet i changed the rs.first() to rs.next() it still works how it normally would, it brings up the jtables when the correct information is entered, but when information is entered that does not exist in the table then it displays the same error again, I want it to say when the information is not found to have my own custom error

Comment: Because you're ignoring what it returns. Will you finally post your code?

Comment: @JBNizet i would but this is coursework from university, and I spent time doing this code, and they use programs to detect plagarism and i would rather not post it up here you see

Comment: Post the relevant code. Shouldn't be more than 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: @John It will be easy for us to help you only if you show us your related code.

Comment: @JBNizet its okay someone below in the answers understood what i meant, now it displays the custom error i wanted

Comment: It was thus just what I told you twice: you're ignoring the result of rs.next()/rs.first().

Comment: What I have explained in the answer @JBNizet has also mentioned in the comments. Anyway its nice to see that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying something like:

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
rs.first();
System.out.println(rs.getString("MY_COLUMN_NAME"));
```

You are getting this error because you are calling `rs.next()` or `rs.first()` as you said in the comments, even if there is no data in the `resultset`.

So instead of try following code to avoid `ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.'` exception.

```
String myCustomMsg="";  //You can return this variable as custom message.
try
{
    Connection con = GET_CONNECTION_HERE;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("QUERY HERE");
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())// This will make sure that if there is no data, don't read the ResultSet
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("MY_COLUMN_NAME"));
        myCustomMsg = "Ok";
    }
    else
        myCustomMsg ="No Data found!";
}
catch(SQLException sqle)
{
    sqle.printStackTrace();
    myCustomMsg ="YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE....";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you understood what I wanted without me putting up the code, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

you can custom SQLException like this

```
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SqlException extends SQLException{

    public SqlException(String message){

        super(message);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SqlException {

        throw new SqlException("name not found .!?");

    }

}
```